# My Project is not connecting to my Postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a tutorial for Prisma, and in the terminal I keep getting access denied when I use the psql command. I was able to override this with a sudo command and in my projects env file I put the correct information for my server.

At this point I cannot create a database, I can only modify the existing ones I have (the preset ones.) Any advice would be much appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2AkL.png)

Comment: Can you share any code or screenshots?

Comment: Can you try running your command with `sudo`?

Comment: Please share the exact error message.  'access denied' is not a PostgreSQL terminology.  That error is coming from the OS.